# show button over image in responsive way without putting large amount of space below image

Tags: html, css

I have an html page which displays three images in a row and I need to place a button over each of them in a responsive way. I want the images to change in size and then be one above the other when the page width is reduced, but I want the button size to also reduce as image reduces in size and I want the button position to remain the same wrt the image.

I found that I needed to use relative positioning for the button but when I do that a large amount of extra space appears below an image. If I use absolute positioning this space doesn't appear but then the button no longer stays positioned on the image when the image size and/or position changes. Also I can't find a way to reduce the button size.

How can I prevent the extra white space appearing and ensure the button stays over the image and how can i make the button size change dynamically when page width is changed?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  color: limegreen;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    float: none;
    width: 360px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .column {
    width: 95%;
  }
}


/* Clearfix (clear floats) */

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}


/* Style the button and place it at the bottom of the container/image */

.container .btn {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -120%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="images.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main row container">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width: 100%" />
      <button class="btn">START TODAY</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Create a working [mre] including images you are talking about... I made a snippet for you, please edit it so we can see the problem.

Comment: I've edited my question and added links to the images. The code has already been reduced to the minimal amount to reproduce the problem. The original html and css files I'm working with are much much larger. So I've already done due diligence on making this a minimal reducible example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i change some css structure in your code.maybe this can help

```css
.main.row.container .column {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  color: limegreen;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    float: none;
    width: 360px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .column {
    width: 95%;
  }
}


/* Clearfix (clear floats) */

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}


/* Style the button and place it at the bottom of the container/image */

.container .btn {
     position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border: solid white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: transparent;
}

.container .btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="images.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main row container">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width: 100%" />
      <button class="btn">START TODAY</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou Satish! Major improvement.. I'm going to experiment to test exactly which changes you make have made the difference but my guess is that these are the main contributors :  overflow: hidden     diisplay: flex;     align-items: center;     vertical-align: middle;        justify-content: center;         flex-wrap: wrap;